# Mac start up bright-grey background for long time

Tags: mac, ios

What does it mean when the start up screen of a Mac shows a dark-grey logo on a bright-grey background for a very long time?

When the Mac is being started, this screen appears for about 2 minutes, and the progressbar slowly progresses:

[image]

At around 80%, the screen turns to this, and the final section of the progressbar progresses within 3-4 seconds:

[image]

According to https://support.apple.com/en-ca/ht204156, the later background appears after boot.efi has been found.

My question would therefore - I think - be what happens while the first background is shown where the progressbar progresses extremely slow.

Before the update to Mac Sierra High, the booting was done in no-time.

Comment: What model Apple computer is it?

Comment: It could be just a old HDD slowly dying, idk'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the previous OS required much less RAM than Sierra.
I upgraded the RAM, reinstalled from scratch, and the problem was gone.
Not a nice solution, but it was the only one that worked for me.
Reinstalling alone didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This article seems to be about your problem :
[Mac boot process stucks on Grey Screen with apple logo after upgrading to macOS Sierra](http://www.hawkdive.com/2017/09/mac-stuck-on-gray-screen-with-apple-logo-during-boot.html) :

> There could be so many possible causes to this grey screen problem, sometimes an incompatible or malfunctioning hardware attached to the Mac or low disk space on your startup disk stalls the Mac during initializing the system processes.

The article explains the Mac boot process and lists many
troubleshooting tips to solve such a problem.
I have listed below the ones I consider the most likely to help,
but you might still have a look at the article itself.

1. Shut down, disconnect all the peripherals and restart
2. Restart in Safe Mode
3. Boot your Mac in Verbose Mode
4. Reset SMC and NVRAM
5. Use Disk Utility in Recovery Mode